# SourceTree crashing when hitting commit

Tags: mercurial, windows-10, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree 1.8.3.0 (I Know this isn't the latest version, but that version immediately crashes when starting up) on Windows 10 64bit. SourceTree crashes when I want to commit, giving me the following error in the log file (sorry automatically translates to Dutch).
This is a 32 bit application but as I said the latest version (1.9.5.0) is even worse.
Does anyone have an idea what is wrong or where I can download a more stable version? 
thanks in advance

```
System.NullReferenceException: De objectverwijzing is niet op een exemplaar van een object ingesteld.
   bij SourceTree.Accounts.AccountManager.GetDefaultUserInformation(String& fullname, String& email) in C:\projects\bitbucket.org\atlassian\sourcetreewin-prod\Accounts\AccountManager.cs:regel 114
   bij SourceTree.ViewModel.UserDetailsViewModel..ctor(Repository repo, Action`2 completionAction, ICustomActionsManager customActionsManager, ISchedulerManager schedulerManager, IRepositoryManager repositoryManager, IAnalyticsDataManager analyticsDataManager, ITraceManager traceManager, IDispatcher sourceTreeDispatcher, IAccountManager accountManager, IFailureHandler failureHandler, IDvcsManager dvcsManager, IRepositoryMonitorManager repositoryMonitorManager, IFileListViewManager fileListViewManager, IFileListContainerViewManager fileListContainerViewManager, IDiffViewManager diffViewManager, IConfigurationManager configurationManager, IProcessDialogViewManager processDialogViewManager, IChangeSetViewManager changeSetViewManager) in C:\projects\bitbucket.org\atlassian\sourcetreewin-prod\SourceTree.Api.UI.Wpf\ViewModel\UserDetailsViewModel.cs:regel 61
   bij SourceTree.ViewModel.CommitAndFileStatusViewModel._CheckMinimumRequirementsBeforeEnterCommit() in C:\projects\bitbucket.org\atlassian\sourcetreewin-prod\SourceTree.Api.UI.Wpf\ViewModel\CommitAndFileStatusViewModel.cs:regel 719
   bij SourceTree.ViewModel.CommitAndFileStatusViewModel.EnterCommitMode() in C:\projects\bitbucket.org\atlassian\sourcetreewin-prod\SourceTree.Api.UI.Wpf\ViewModel\CommitAndFileStatusViewModel.cs:regel 611
   bij System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.IsFocused_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyPropertyKey key, Object value)
   bij System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.OnFocusedElementChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   bij System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   bij System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(DependencyObject element, IInputElement value)
   bij System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation.UpdateFocusedElement(DependencyObject focusTarget)
   bij System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnGotKeyboardFocus(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   bij System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   bij System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   bij System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   bij System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.ChangeFocus(DependencyObject focus, Int32 timestamp)
   bij System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.TryChangeFocus(DependencyObject newFocus, IKeyboardInputProvider keyboardInputProvider, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
   bij System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(DependencyObject focus, Boolean askOld, Boolean askNew, Boolean forceToNullIfFailed)
   bij System.Windows.Input.KeyboardDevice.Focus(IInputElement element)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()
   bij System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.MoveFocusToUiScope(TextEditor This)
   bij System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.OnMouseDown(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   bij System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   bij System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   bij System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   bij System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   bij System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   bij System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   bij System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   bij System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   bij MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   bij MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   bij System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   bij System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Answer (score 5):

The same behavior occurs with version 3.2.6. When pressing the Commit button sourcetree crashes. The problem could be solved by deactivating the global user settings.

[image]

Please excuse the German language setting.

Comment: Solved it in my case as well. Just one mention: make sure you restart SourceTree after applying these settings.